# QSpinBox not drawn correctly

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qt4.8, qstyle

I'm currently implementing a custom delegate, in part of which I need a `QSpinBox` to be drawn in the `paint(..)` method.

```
void Sy_floatingPointPD::paint( QPainter* painter,
                                const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                                const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    painter->save();

    //  Paint check box.
    QStyleOptionSpinBox spOpt;
    spOpt.palette     = option.palette;
    spOpt.rect        = option.rect;
    spOpt.state       = option.state;
    spOpt.frame       = true;
    spOpt.stepEnabled = QAbstractSpinBox::StepUpEnabled |
                       QAbstractSpinBox::StepDownEnabled;

    style->drawComplexControl( QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &spOpt, painter );

    painter->restore();
}
```

Unfortunately it appears as:

[image: Paint failure]

As you can see the step buttons are drawn *massive* and only the down arrow appears.  Interestingly the width of the buttons mirrors that of the first table column, despite `option.rect` being the size of the cell (which is correct, which is presumably why the frame is drawn correctly).

Any ideas what information I'm not giving `QStyle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jens over at the qt-project forums answered this question, so I'll link to it [here](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25573/).

In short, there is a design flaw in the spin box drawing (at least in QGtkStyle) whereby it only uses the *size* of the `option.rect`, ignoring it's position.  Although this perfectly reasonable in a 'normal' painting scenario because it maps to the widget origin, it fails when rendered in an item view due to the cell offset.

To solve this, move `option.rect` to the widget origin (i.e. move it's top left corner to (0,0)), and then translate the `QPainter` to take into account the cell offset.